# Performance Issues on DateTime Columns - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below Filter in the Query which is extracting the records very fast.

`Last_Update_Date>TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2018-01-03 00:00:00',0,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

But If I have below Filter in the same Query, It's taking long time to extract the data.

`Last_Update_Date>TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2018-01-03 12:12:12',0,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

I mean if the timestamp is `00:00:00` its taking less time and if the timestamp is having some value it's taking more time.

Any pointers why this is happening?

Comment: Any indexing or partitioning on the table?

Comment: @JohnHC - There's no index on Last_Update_Date column.

Comment: The Datatype of Last_Update_Date is Date.

Comment: What is the purpose of `SUBSTR(...,0,19)`?

Comment: What are the execution plans?

Comment: @beckham, if `Last_Update_Date` is a `date` type, why do you even need the time portion of the constant you're providing? And what's with all the `SUBSTRING` and `TO_DATE`? Just put a date literal in as follows: `DATE'2017-01-01'`

Comment: @ Wernfield - Actually `2018-01-03 00:00:00` value is being passed from another table as a variable. That Field is Date too.                                            Actual Code looks like this `Last_Update_Date>TO_DATE(SUBSTR('#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE',0,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: @beckham, if you're joining onto another table, and both columns are dates, then you just perform direct comparison - you don't convert the values.

Comment: @Steve - Actually 2018-01-03 00:00:00 value is being passed from another table as a variable. That Field is Date too. Actual Code looks like this Last_Update_Date>TO_DATE(SUBSTR('#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE',‌​0,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: @beckham, try this: `Last_Update_Date > #BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE`. If you're still getting poor performance, we'd have to look at the query itself and the query plan that results from its execution.

Comment: @ Steve - When I try to `Last_Update_Date > #BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE. It says `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"`

Comment: Is the slowness happening when the query is run with the two literal values (I.e. the strings with and without 00:00:00 as the time part), or when the values are passed across as variables? If the latter, it's possible that a different execution plan is being used - possibly because stats are out of date or some other reason.

Comment: @beckham, that suggests one column or the other (presumably `#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE`) is being stored as a string type, and not as you say a date type. Ultimately, this alone is inefficient. As others have said, we can only really be any clearer in answering your question about the varying performance under the different conditions if you post three query plans for us to compare - one using a date constant without a time, one using a date constant with the time portion, and one with the query involving real data being compared between the two actual tables.

Comment: @Steve - Yes That's right. Although LAST_EXTRACT_DATE is extracted from another table as Date Datatype, the data type for the variable inside the application is AlphaNumeric.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the values as literals:

```
Last_Update_Date > TIMESTAMP '2018-01-03 00:00:00'
```

This makes it clearer to the optimizer what the value is.

If the value is coming from a column or variable (sort of suggested by the `substr()` function), then all bets are off.  There is a big difference between a value known at compile time and one that is not known.

Comment: @ Gordon Lintoff - Yes the value is coming from a variable.

Comment: @beckham, post the entire query or stored procedure for us to have a look at.

Comment: @ Steve - Not a problem to post the entire query. But its 240 Lines of code

Comment: @beckham, there's already getting on for 240 lines of comments from various posters, all trying to fathom it out like blind men grasping at the different body parts of an elephant, so you may as well post the query!

Comment: @Steve - I posted another question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121118/same-query-same-server-different-filter-conditions-on-dates

Comment: @beckham, but the new question still lacks query code or query plans! Blind men and the elephant!