# Same Query Same Server Different Filter Conditions on Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Query that's behaving differently for different dates. The Filer Condition in the Query is as below

`Last_Update_Date>TO_DATE(SUBSTR('#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE',0,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

The value for variable `#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE` is being passed from a Application and datatype is Alphanumeric for `#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE`.

If the Value passed to `#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE` is `2017-12-20 00:00:00` this Query is extracting 200K records in 10 Mins.

If the Value passed to `#BIAPPS.LAST_EXTRACT_DATE` is `2018-01-02 00:00:00` this Query is extracting 80K records in 120 Mins.

Any Reason the Oracle behaves like this and Do I need to correct anything?

Comment: Is this the only filter condition? Or are there others as well? Are there any joins in the query? The reason I ask: with the more restrictive condition on dates, the optimizer may choose a different access path. The optimizer may choose a sub-optimal path after you change the filter; either because your stats aren't up to date (are they?) or because the optimizer is not smart enough (especially if the overall query is complicated). Perhaps an optimizer hint would help, but that should be the last solution you try, not the first.

Comment: @mathguy - There are other joins and Filters as well. Would you be please tell me know how to check if the stats are up to date, Since the same filter condition is being used to restrict the data from 4 different tables. Is there a way like I can send you the whole query?

Comment: @mathguy - I just ran the EXPLAIN PLAN for both the queries and yes it looks like they were using different access paths for different dates. In one of the path(the one which is running slower) it's not using a Index at all, which is being used by the path that's running faster.

Comment: I guess with the more restrictive filter on dates, Oracle thinks it will be faster to use an index on dates. That would be OK if the stats were accurate (and if the distribution of rows over dates was uniform - otherwise you may need to add histograms, or a hint...) Hard to help without seeing the plans. To find out when was the last time statistics were run: Here is how I can check on the HR schema (all tables): `select * from all_tab_stats_history where owner = 'HR'
;`

Comment: I have just checked. It looks like the stats are last updated on Jan1st 2018. Is that posing the problem by any chance?

Comment: Could be - if a lot of data was added after Jan 1st. Run stats on the table, or ask your DBA to do so, and try the queries again. You will learn something either way: either that the stats being refreshed will correct the problem, or if not, that you need to look further. It's certainly the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that in the first case it is using an index on LAST_EXTRACT_DATE, while in the second case it is not. (Another guess is that the reverse is true, and the query without the index is actually faster.)

The best first step to diagnose the problem is to view the execution plan for both queries.  If you don't know how to do that, you may find questions related to it here.  The quick way in SQLPlus is SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY EXPLAIN.

I assume you mean that you are doing text substitution into this query template, so from the Oracle parser's point of view they are two different queries.  One possible solution to your problem would be to use a bind variable instead, so the parser would see both as the same query and use the same execution plan. (At least, it probably would; in recent versions of Oracle there can be more variation for the same query.)  However, this *could* lead to a situation where you get the "bad" execution plan in more cases.

Based on the fact you are using very recent dates, a possible root cause is that the statistics on this table have been gathered sometime between the two dates in question.  So the parser has a good estimate of how many records the first query will return based on recorded column statistics and/or histogram; but for the second query it needs to do an extrapolation since the date is outside the range of values recorded in the statistics.  (I saw this a lot in a system I used to work on.)

In that case, another possible solution is to explicitly refresh statistics on that table every night.  This may not help if the query uses today's date, but if all the queries use dates before today, it may work well.

There are also various ways to force/guide Oracle to use a desired execution plan.  The old-fashioned one is explicit hinting.  In this case, if my first guess was correct, you might add an INDEX hint to the query.  There have been a number of features added to Oracle over the years to help with this.  I think the current primary one is called "SQL Plan Management" so you could research that.